# android logcat grep and output FAILED

Tags: android, windows, file, grep, logcat

I want to save the grep logcat to file on windows8.

```
adb logcat | grep AAA > D:1.txt
```

it does not work

and

```
adb logcat | grep --line-buffered AAA > D:1.txt
```

it does not work too. It said

> grep:unrecognized option '--line-buffered' Usage:grep --help for more
>   infomation

But **adb logcat | grep MyApp** ,  it works well
And **adb logcat -v time >D:1.txt**  it works well too

Comment: I've edited the question to change the `output` tag with the `windows` one. I think it could be more helpful for other users trying to give an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create file name with ":" in windows so please change your destination file name like also make sure windows have grep installed

```
adb logcat | grep AAA > D1.txt
```

Comment: /system/bin/sh: can't create D1.txt: Read-only file system

Comment: I think you are running this command in android adb shell right? you have to run this command in windows cmd

Comment: C:\Users\PALAK>adb logcat | grep AAA > D1.txt
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: that not the key problem, your code can not work too

Comment: You need to install grep command for windows http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Comment: but i can use the code like this 
adb logcat | grep AAA

Comment: I can use  adb logcat | grep MyApp , do i real need to install the "grep for windows"

Comment: I have installed the "grep for windows"，but the problem is still exist